# Code working in Spark-Shell not in eclipse

Tags: scala, apache-spark, eclipse-plugin

I have a small Scala code which works properly on Spark-Shell but not in Eclipse with Scala plugin. I can access hdfs using plugin tried writing another file and it worked..

FirstSpark.scala

```
package bigdata.spark
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import java. io. _
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._

object FirstSpark {

  def main(args: Array[String])={
    val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("FirstSparkProgram")
    val sparkcontext = new SparkContext(conf)
    val textFile =sparkcontext.textFile("hdfs://pranay:8020/spark/linkage")
    val m = new Methods()
    val q =textFile.filter(x => !m.isHeader(x)).map(x=> m.parse(x))
    q.saveAsTextFile("hdfs://pranay:8020/output")    } 
}
```

Methods.scala

```
package bigdata.spark
import java.util.function.ToDoubleFunction

class Methods {
def isHeader(s:String):Boolean={
    s.contains("id_1")
}
def parse(line:String) ={
    val pieces = line.split(',')
    val id1=pieces(0).toInt
    val id2=pieces(1).toInt
    val matches=pieces(11).toBoolean
    val mapArray=pieces.slice(2, 11).map(toDouble)
    MatchData(id1,id2,mapArray,matches)
  }
def toDouble(s: String) = {
    if ("?".equals(s)) Double.NaN else s.toDouble
}
}
case class MatchData(id1: Int, id2: Int,
scores: Array[Double], matched: Boolean)
```

Error Message:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable
at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:304)
at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:294)
at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:122)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.clean(SparkContext.scala:2032)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$filter$1.apply(RDD.scala:335)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$filter$1.apply(RDD.scala:334)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:147)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:108)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:310)
```

Can anyone please help me with this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing `class Methods { .. }` to `object Methods { .. }`.

I think the problem is at `val q =textFile.filter(x => !m.isHeader(x)).map(x=> m.parse(x))`. When Spark sees the `filter` and `map` functions it tries to serialize the functions passed to them (`x => !m.isHeader(x)` and `x=> m.parse(x)`) so that it can dispatch the work of executing them to all of the executors (this is the Task referred to). However, to do this, it needs to serialize `m`, since this object is referenced inside the function (it is in the closure of the two anonymous methods) - but it cannot do this since `Methods` is not serializable. You could add `extends Serializable` to the `Methods` class, but in this case an `object` is more appropriate (and is already Serializable).

Comment: @Pranay Glad I helped! For completeness, even if you had used `x => !(new Methods()).isHeader(x)` you would still have had the same problem since Spark would try to serialize the whole of `Methods` just to get the definition of `isHeader`.